# What 'this' refers to in building an intent

Tags: java, android

I just started learning Android and studying the tutorials on the google android website.

In the tutorial I am going through, I am building an intent to start another activity.

```
com.mycompany.myfirstapp;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;   
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /**Called when the user clicks the Send button**/
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        //Do something in response to button
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    }
}
```

The tutorial says "A Context as its first parameter (this is used because the Activity class is a subclass of Context)."

I guess this explanation should be clear enough, but I don't get it.

What I understand is that 'this' inside sendMessage method refers to a current class, so serves as a instance variable of the current class, which is MyActivity.

Is this true?

If that's true, then its type is Activity? which is again a subclass of Context?

I don't understand why the type of 'this' is Activity.
Please explain this for me. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I understand is that 'this' inside sendMessage method refers to a current class, so serves as a instance variable of the current class. Is this true?

Correct.

> If that's true, then its type is Activity?

It's type is `MyActivity` which extends (indirectly) `Activity`, so you can pass it here.

> which is again a subclass of Context?

Correct.

`MyActivity` extends `AppCompatActivity` which extends `FragmentActivity` which extends `Activity` which extends `Context` (some steps omitted). So, whenever you need a `Context` instance, you can pass an `Activity` instance, that's how inheritance works.

**Edit:**
`Class` and `Activity` are not the same. `Activity` is one of the Android SDK's classes. Class is like a template which you can use to create an instance of new object. `Intent`'s constructor requires you to pass the instance of `Context` in its first parameter. `MyActivity` extends `Context`, so you can pass the instance of `MyActivity` in the `Intent`'s costructor. `this` inside the method holds the reference to the *current object*.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. But I don't understand the second one. Why is the type of 'this' is Activity? It's a class. Activity and class, are they the same thing in Android?

Comment: @Nayana - it's not Android, it's java. All objects are classes / have a class (not sure the proper phrasing there)

Comment: I get it now. Thank you. Your last explanation was very clear. I should have known what "extends" means.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `this` is the instance of the current class (`MyActivity` in your case). And as your `Activity` is extending `AppCompatActivity` it extends all its parents as well:

```
    android.content.Context
   ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
       ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
           ↳    android.app.Activity
               ↳    android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
                   ↳    android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is an instance of `Activity`, because that's what `AppCompatActivity` extends.

For further reference, see:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html